# Spring 3 MVC and modal wizards

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I'm looking at integrating a wizard in an existing Spring 3 MVC+JPA+Jquery+JSP application. I  would prefer the wizard to be based on jquery modal overalays, however am open to considering other frameworks if necessary.

I looked at Spring Webflow - but am not able to figure out how to get it working with modal overlays. I did find one tutorial http://realworldagile.wordpress.com/2009/10/06/modal-wizard-forms-using-spring-webflow-2-0-8-and-richfaces/ but it is tied to RichFaces.

I am not able to figure out

1. how to launch a wizard in an overlay
2. how to transition from one overlay screen to another - as part of the state transitions.
3. how to do server-side validations within the overlay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use subflows : http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/html/ch03s09.html

This way you can follow a secondary flow (the wizard part) before returning back to the current one. Kind of the same as a modal overlay from a functional perspective, but with all standard WebFlow mechanisms and features (e.g. server-side validation).

Answer (score 0):

I think, if it possible - don't use SS validation within steps in wizard. Possible, if you can implement wizard pattern only in client side, because you don't need partially correct data on server (some conversation pages done, but some don't). Course, you can attach jBPM, activity, Spring WEB Flow to solve this problem, but i think for most wizards need only something like [this](http://okonet.ru/projects/modalbox/index.html). User fill data in all steps at one page, you validate and collect it in JS side, after him click "Finish" - you send data and validate again in SS.

Answer (score 0):

If using webflow, it seems the answer is to use web flow in 'embedded' mode (see [embedded mode](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/spring-webflow-reference/htmlsingle/spring-webflow-reference.html#spring-mvc-embedded-flow)). Particularly, your ajax handler in jQuery will be replacing the content of the modal dialogue with fragments sent from the server (see [ajax](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/spring-webflow-reference/htmlsingle/spring-webflow-reference.html#spring-js-ajax)).

Personally, I have used this jQuery UI [wizard](http://www.noveltheory.com/Wizard/) plugin; in this approach, you generate the model and it is sent by Spring MVC from the controller using json, which you use programmatically in your jQuery ajax handler, which in turn is linked to the steps of the wizard. I think this would be your more manual alternative.